# Can I receive HTTP Format packet (raw data) by using VPC Mirroring on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mirroring, traffic-management

AWS launched a new service named VPC Traffic Mirroring.
I wonder if I can receive HTTP Format packet(raw data) by using this service on between ALB(src) and NLB(dst).

Do I have to decrypt this mirrored packet for view raw format(HTTP) ?